# How can we Display and store a binary search tree in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, binary-tree

I have written the program for Binary Search Tree but does not know how can i save it in the Django Database. How can i store it in the models:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Node:

# Constructor to initialize data
# If data is not given by user,its taken as None 
def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

# __str__ returns string equivalent of Object
def __str__(self):
    return "Node[Data = %s]" % (self.data,)

class BinarySearchTree:
def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
```

While inserting values in a binary search tree, we first check whether the value is greater than, lesser than or equal to the root of the tree. We initialize current node as the root. If the value is greater than the current node value, then we know that its right location will be in the right subtree. So we make the current element as the right node.
If the value is lesser than the current node value, then we know that its right location will be in the left subtree. So we make the current element as the left node.
If the value is equal to the current node value, then we know that the value is already contained in the tree and doesn't need to be reinserted. So we break from the loop.

```
 def insert(self, val):
    if (self.root == None):
        self.root = Node(val)
    else:
        current = self.root

        while 1:
            if (current.data > val):
                if (current.left == None):
                    current.left = Node(val)
                    break
                else:
                    current = current.left

            elif (current.data < val):
                if (current.right == None):
                    current.right = Node(val)
                    break
                else:
                    current = current.right

            else:
                break
```

In preorder traversal, we first print the current element, then move on to the left subtree and finally to the right subree.

```
def preorder(self, node):
    if (node == None):
        return
    else:
        print(node.data, end=" ")
        self.preorder(node.left)
        self.preorder(node.right)
```

In inorder traversal, we first move to the left subtree, then print the current element and finally move to the right subtree.

```
#Important : Inorder traversal returns the elements in sorted form.
def inorder(self, node):
    if (node == None):
        return
    else:
        self.inorder(node.left)
        print(node.data, end=" ")
        self.inorder(node.right)
```

In postorder traversal, we first move to the left subtree, then to the right subtree and finally print the current element.

```
def postorder(self, node):
    if (node == None):
        return
    else:
        self.postorder(node.left)
        self.postorder(node.right)
        print(node.data, end=" ")

tree = BinarySearchTree()
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(9)
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(5)
tree.insert(7)
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(0)
print ("Preorder Printing")
tree.preorder(tree.root)
print("\n\nInorder Printing")
tree.inorder(tree.root)
print("\n\nPostOrder Printing")
tree.postorder(tree.root)
```

User can add and delete a tree and On adding a tree, user should be prompted to enter at least 3 nodes...
A binary search tree structure should be displayed when a tree is selected, with its
respective nodes in the order of insertion.....
How can all the changes that have been done by the user can be reflected back into the database..

Comment: display means gui????

Comment: @Jainil Patel Yes GUI

Comment: What does this mean like tree with many??

Comment: gui display , the tree with / \  \ / edges like this \ and nodes attached  ??

Comment: ok but how can i store it in the database??